# Why all the endless failed to start build errors in my TEAM CITY server log file?

Tags: build, teamcity

```
[2012-01-25 17:03:09,186]   WARN -   jetbrains.buildServer.SERVER - Failed to start build: null, error: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I just keep getting these errors as my build agent sits idle and a build is in the queue.

Any ideas what may be buggered in the config that can help me?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if it has anything to do with past versions of teamcity.  Have you *upgraded* it recently?  If so... maybe it can be fixed by doing what @Seth said here(1):

> This was apparently caused by some old 6.0.3 code hanging around.  Did rm -rf on webapps/ROOT and replaced again with the new code and it works now.

**EDIT:**
Have you tried doing a clean install of TeamCity?  It sounds like that worked for someone using it on Windows, according to these comments(2):

> "The problem is that in this case, old files left in the installation directory, some of these files are TeamCity plugins. TeamCity finds them and loads instead of new versions, this causes further problems. Please try to perform clean install." - Pavel Sher

References:

1. http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-17687?query=NULL
2. http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-17031#tab=Comments

Comment: sounds like unix stuff there. is there an equivalent for windows users?

Comment: I edited the answer above to include someone that was using TeamCity on Windows while experiencing the same issue.  Basically, it sounds like doing a clean install of TeamCity worked for some people.  But make sure to backup your existing install, if you choose to try a clean install.

Comment: i think i fixed it by doing a clean uninstall, deleting all files from the install folder after uninstall completed. teamcity is building again. seems it had, in fact, to do with past version...